# Did specific countries have special influence in the founding of the UN?

Tags: united-states, china, asia, united-nations

I'm having a presentation on the influence of non European countries in the foundation of the UN. I was wondering was specific points especially China and the US had that got into the foundation of the UN?
Also if you know some other countries outside Europe that had influence in the founding of the UN.

Comment: Sorry sir, but it isnt. Can't find anything on this on Wikipedia!

Answer (score 2):

The [United Nations grew out of the organisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_United_Nations) of the Allied side of the Second World War, who were formally known as the United Nations from the beginning of 1942. To join at that stage, a government had to sign the [Declaration by United Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_by_United_Nations), and declare war on the Axis powers.

The declaration had been drafted by FDR, Churchill and Harry Hopkins, in December 1941, so US influence was present from the beginning. The five permanent members of the Security Council are the five major Allied powers of WWII: the USA, the UK, France, the USSR (later replaced by Russia) and the Republic of China (later replaced by the PRC).